# The inverse of $2x^2+2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/( x^3+2x^2+2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

What is the independent coefficient in the inverse of $2x^2+2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^3+2x^2+2)$ ?

I have been calculating some combinations, but I don't know how I can calculate the inverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** $\, {\rm mod}\ 3\!:\ g = x^3\!+\!2x\!+\!2 \equiv  (x\!+\!1)(x^2\!+\!x\!-\!1).\, $ Compute $\, f = \dfrac{1}{2x^2\!+\!2}\,$ by CRT:

${\rm mod}\,\ \color{#0a0}{x^2\!+\!x\!-\!1}\!:\ \color{brown}{x^2}\equiv 1\!-\!x\,\Rightarrow\,f = \dfrac{1}{2\color{brown}{x^2}\!+\!2} \equiv \dfrac{1}{x+1} \equiv \color{#c00}x,\ $ by $\ x(x\!+\!1) \equiv 1$

${\rm mod}\,\ x\!+\!1\!:\ x\equiv -1\,\Rightarrow\,1\equiv f\equiv \color{#c00}x+(\color{#0a0}{x^2\!+\!x\!-\!1})c \equiv -1 -c\,\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c0f}{c \equiv  1}$

Therefore, we conclude that  $\ f \equiv x+(x^2\!+\!x\!-\!1)\color{#c0f}{(1)}\, \pmod{g} $

Answer (score 1):

It must take the form $ax^2+bx+c$.
Multiply this by $2x^2+2$, and you get a degree-four polynomial.
Since $x^3+2x+2=0$, it follows that $x^3=x+1$ and so $x^4=x(x^3)=x^2+x$.
So your degree-four polynomial becomes a quadratic.
This quadratic equals 1, or $0x^2+0x+1$.
Equate the three coefficients, and get three linear equations in $a,b,c$.

Comment: My equation is $x^3+2x^2+2$. With your idea, I have calculated:

$x^4= x^2+x+1$.

$(2x^2+2)(ax^2+bx+c) = x^2 (4a+2b+2c)+x(2a+2b)+(2a+2b+2c)$.

So, if I solve the system:

$4a+2b+2c=0 ; 2a+2b=0 ; 2a+2b+2c=1$ a=1,b=2,c=2, so the indpendent cofficient is 1?

Comment: I suppose the independent coefficient would be $c$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I have said 1 because I have calculated a+b+c, but c is my independent coefficient. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set $f(x) = 2x^2+2$, $g(x) = x^3+2x^2+2$. Since $f(x),g(x)$ are coprime, find

$$p(x)f(x)+q(x)g(x) = 1$$
using Euclidean division.

Then $p(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$ in $F[x]/\langle g(x)\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

This is in no way a standard solution, but I just want to include it for fun.

Note that $x^3=-(2x^2+2)$, we will find $x^{-3}$. Now
$$x^3-x^2=-2=1$$
implies 
$$x(x^2-x)=x^2(x-1)=1.$$
Thus 
$$x^{-1}=x(x-1)\text{ and }x^{-2}=x-1.$$
Multiplying the two we get
$$x^{-3} = x(x-1)^2=x(x^2+x+1)=x^3+x^2+x.$$
Using $x^3=x^2+1$ on the RHS, we see that
$$x^{-3}=2x^2+x+1.$$
Thus
$$(2x^2+2)^{-1} = -x^{-3} = -2x^2-x-1 = x^2+2x+2.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
(ax^2 + bx + c)(2x^2 + 2) + (dx + e)(x^3 + 2x + 2) = 1\\
(2a + d)x^4 + (2b + e)x^3 + (2a + 2c + 2d)x^2 + (2b + 2d + 2e)x + (2c + 2e) = 1\\
$$

$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccccc} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{array} \right] 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
a \\ b \\ c \\ d \\ e \\ \end{array} \right]
=
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ \end{array} \right]
$$

Solve for $a$, $b$, and $c$ and you find the inverse.